# "Dank' " oder "Dank"?

Tags: word-usage, spelling

Ist der Gebrauch des Wortes `Dank` eine Verkürzung des Wortes `Danke`, der sich nur mit der Zeit dahingehend gewandelt hat, dass der Gebrauch nicht äquivalent ist?

D.h. muss in einem solchen Fall:

> Hab' Dank für die Information!

oder in einem solchen:

> Hallo Alice,
>
> kannst Du mir bitte Deinen Public-Key zukommen lassen?
>
> Dank und Gruß, Bob

das Wort `Dank` eigentlich von einem Apostroph begleitet werden, also `Dank'` geschrieben werden?

Bemerkung: Während im ersten Fall der Gebrauch von `Danke` falsch wäre, wäre er im zweiten zulässig, sodass sich hier möglicherweise die Antwort unterscheiden könnte. Wie dem auch sei, dies sind Beispiele; Gesucht ist eine allgemeine Antwort (so weit möglich).

---

When to write `Dank'` and when to write `Dank`? Which one is (more) correct?

Comment: Selbst *[ich] hab* wird in der Regel ohne Apostroph geschrieben, da es hier sehr üblich ist, das *e* wegzulassen. *Dank* ist natürlich noch ein viel klarerer Fall.

Comment: Es *muss* ohne Apostroph sein, denn das Substantiv ist "Dank" und nicht "Danke"!

Comment: Is the first sentence of the above question entirely clear and grammatically correct?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Dank'` mit Apostroph ist mir in dieser Verwendungsweise praktisch noch nie begegnet (was aber nichts heißen muss …). Jedenfalls gibt es neben der [Partikel](http://canoonet.eu/services/Controller?dispatch=glossary&input=Partikel&language=0&project=1) [danke](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/danke) und dem Verb [`danken`](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/danken) auch das Substantiv [`der Dank`](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Dank), das in beiden Beispielen verwendet werden kann. `Danke` (die Partikel) passt hingegen nur im zweiten Beispiel, weil `hab Dank` - `Dank haben` eine feststehende Wendung ist. Zudem besitzt der Satz mit „Hab'“ (von `haben`) schon ein Verb.

Das Grimm'sche Wörterbuch listet übrigens unter den fremdsprachigen Äquivalenten zu [`Dank`](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?lemma=dank) das englische Substantiv [`thank`](https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/thank) auf, das wahrscheinlich ähnlich wie der deutsche `Dank` weitgehend hinter das „umgangssprachlichere“ `danke` / `thanks` zurückgetreten ist.

Um die abschließende Frage vorab zu beantworten: Es kommt auf die **grammatikalische Funktion** im Satz an. Im Falle des **Substantivs** wird m. E. praktisch nie ein Apostroph stehen, ebenso wenig wird m. E. die **Partikel** `Danke!` per Apostroph abgekürzt. Beim **Verb** hingegen kann ein auslautendes e mittels Apostroph gekürzt werden.

Damit scheidet m. E. auch in beiden Beispielen die Verwendung des Apostrophs aus, da `Dank` in beiden Fällen jeweils nicht als Verbform steht. Im ersten Fall kann es nur das Substantiv sein, im zweiten entweder Substantiv oder Partikel. Sollte die Partikel gemeint sein, würde ich sie auch aus stilistischen Gründen eher nicht abkürzen: Die Formel `Danke und Gruß` ist schon kurz genug; sie noch weiter zu kürzen, fände ich etwas seltsam.

Comment: Ah, die unterschiedliche Verwendung bei Verb und Substantiv hatte ich komplett ausgeblendet. Hab vielen Dank :)

Comment: Das Apostroph wäre schon insofern sinnvoll, als dass es in vielen Notationen einen Glotteral-Stop kennzeichnet, der auch in Dank vorkommt. Das nur vorab. Wichtiger als die "abschließende Frage" wäre erstmal die eingehende Frage zu klären, die durch die ausgehende weder abgeschlossen noch beantwortet wird. Ich zitiere: "Ist der Gebrauch des Wortes Dank eine Verkürzung des Wortes Danke, der sich nur mit der Zeit dahingehend gewandelt hat, dass der Gebrauch nicht äquivalent ist?" Nur so der Vollständigkeit halber: [Kronen] says it's an a-stem; these lost the ablaut it seems, cp "Tang". ...

Comment: ... so you would be correct, and I'd agree to the extend that it may have been historically compared to *denken*, *Gedanke* (which is not an a-stem). This were a satisfying answer, except there's no obvious proof, which is important in case vice-versa *denken* was a secondary derivation instead, while other comparisons for *danke* can be sought e.g. in *da*, cp. *voila* and *bitte* "please" vs *bitte sehr* "there, sehr you go" (please excuse the pun :-) ... furthermore, \*thagen, \*thaggon, relating to silence, cp Fr *mercie* vs En *mercy* as Ger *Reue* vs *Ruhe*? There there. Danke das reicht

Answer (score 13):

In your examples you are using the noun "der Dank", so there is no apostrophe needed. Only for the verb "danken" an apostrophe might be needed:

> Ich dank' dir von ganzem Herzen.

Comment: Beim Entfallen eines "e" am Wortende wird kein Apostroph gesetzt.

Comment: @Bevor: Das stimmt nicht. Nach alter Rechtschreibung ist der Apostroph hier zwingend, nach neuer Rechtschreibung ist er möglich.

Answer (score 4):

Das Wort "Dank" ist ein vollständiges Wort und nicht nur ein Stamm. Deshalb darf kein Apostroph gesetzt werden.

Answer (score 1):

Ein Apostroph würde gehen bei *"Dank' dir!"* als Verkürzung von *"Ich danke dir"*.

*"Dank'"* in dem Fall nur deswegen groß geschrieben, weil es am Satzanfang steht.